# Adding Color to Java /Html script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add color to each table created by the scripts below.  I dont want them all to be the same color.  Preferable, I would want one to be red and the other green.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <!-- <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="ryan.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
        d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I only included one of the scripts.

Comment: I'd suggest this should be tagged CSS instead since that's the proper way to achieve this in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: But how would you do that for multiple tables?  Say i stack the scripts, so that it displays 2 tables on top of each other.  THe css will affect both tables and not the individual table.